# p:selectOneMenu doesn't receive focus on tab key navigation

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, focus, selectonemenu, keyboard-navigation

I have a form with `<p:inputText>` and `<p:selectOneMenu>` components next to each other. When the focus is on the input text and I press the tab key in order to navigate to select one menu by keyboard, then the focus is lost. I don't see which component is focused.

How can I get the focus on the select one menu when I tab into it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `tabindex` property of `<p:inputText>` and `<p:selectOneMenu>`, as explained in the [documentation](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Using the `tabindex` property makes it possible to navigate between `<p:inputText>` and `<p:selectOneMenu>`. What worked for me was to see set the `tabindex` in `<p:inputText>` to *n* and *n+1* in `<p:selectOneMenu>`. I used `n = 90`.