# Input fields losing focus on tab key press when SelectItem has null value in a SelectOneMenu (jsf2, icefaces)

Tags: jsf, datatable, icefaces

This is the same problem addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033979/pselectonemenu-doesnt-receive-focus-on-tab-key-navigation). The problem is solved when tabIndex is used. I can't dove it like that because i'm using a modified version of ICEFACES we compiled to not add those tabIndex.

We have a "dynamic form" page built using a dataTable and label-field pairs in each row, if we keep the tabIndex attribute then the tab action will focus the entire next row instead of focusing only de input field in the next row.

So as you can see i'm having the (if you want this, that won't work and vice versa) problem.

The blur event occurs only when you are focusing a SelectOneMenu with the null value SelectItem selected.

I have tried

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="" />
```

and

```
<f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="" />
```

to prevent this behavior but neither seems to work.

Any advice in how can i address this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried this in our project to avoid the problem ,

Icefaces renders the event as `Ice.selectChange(form,this,event,300);setFocus(this);`

Below will execute all events except the focus call in icefaces javascript.

```
<ice:selectOneMenu partialSubmit="false" 
          onchange="Ice.selectChange(form,this,event,300);">
...
</ice:selectOneMenu>
```